# Writing to mutable property for a struct record is not allowed in F#. Why?

Tags: f#

When I have the following code:

```
[<Struct>]
type Person = { mutable FirstName:string ; LastName : string}

let john = { FirstName = "John"; LastName = "Connor"}

john.FirstName <- "Sarah";
```

The compiler complains that "A value must be mutable in order to mutate the contents".  However when I remove the Struct attribute it works fine. Why is that so ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This protects you from a gotcha that used to plague the `C#` world a few years back: *structs are passed by value*.

Note that the red squiggly (if you're in IDE) appears not under `FirstName`, but under `john`. The compiler complains not about changing the value of `john.FirstName`, but about changing the value of `john` itself.

With non-structs, there is an important distinction between the reference and the referenced object:

[image]

Both the reference and the object itself can be mutable. So that you can either mutate the reference (i.e. make it point to a different object), or you can mutate the object (i.e. change the contents of its fields).

With structs, however, this distinction does not exist, because there is no reference:

[image]

This means that when you mutate `john.FirstName`, you also mutate `john` itself. They are one and the same.

Therefore, in order to perform this mutation, you need to declare `john` itself as mutable too:

```
[<Struct>]
type Person = { mutable FirstName:string ; LastName : string}

let mutable john = { FirstName = "John"; LastName = "Connor"}

john.FirstName <- "Sarah"  // <-- works fine now
```

---

**For further illustration**, try this in C#:

```
struct Person
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}

class SomeClass
{
    public Person Person { get; } = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" };
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var c = new SomeClass();
        c.Person.FirstName = "Jack";
    }
}
```

The IDE will helpfully underline `c.Person` and tell you that you *"Cannot modify the return value of 'SomeClass.Person' because it is not a variable"*.

Why is that? Every time you write `c.Person`, that is translated into calling the property getter, which is just like another method that returns you a `Person`. But because `Person` is passed by value, that returned `Person` is going to be a different `Person` every time. The getter cannot return you references to the same object, because there can be no references to a struct. And therefore, any changes you make to this returned value will not be reflected in the original `Person` that lives inside `SomeClass`.

Before this helpful compiler error existed, a lot of people would do this:

```
c.Person.FirstName = "Jack"; // Why the F doesn't it change? Must be compiler bug!
```

I clearly remember answering this question almost daily. Those were the days! :-)